# How do I edit the source code of a docker image?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I hope you are doing well.

I'm trying to rebuild a docker image.

What I mean is, I don't just want to get some files into the file system of the image, but want to edit the source code/the codebase itself... whatever it's called.

Especially, I'd like to make the image instances leave some log information.

But I'm totally clueless what to edit(even I can't find the source base code of that image)

Could you please help me edit the source code if you know how?

I would really appreciate. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to make the image instances leave some log information

This requirement may be reached with [`bind mounts`](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/):

```
$ docker run -d \
  -it \
  --name container-name \
  -v "$(pwd)"/logs:/app/logs \
  your-image
```

Here, `$(pwd)/logs` is a directory on your host filesystem that will contain the logs, and `/app/logs` is a directory that your application uses to write logs inside the container. Of course, you need to modify these according to your needs.

The other requirement might as well be achieved in a similar way:

> I don't just want to get some files into the file system of the image, but want to edit the source code/the codebase itself

It depends on the tech stack you use for development. For example, if your app is written in PHP, you can mount source code folder to the container, and each time you modify a file, the same version will "appear" inside the container, since PHP is an interpreted language that does not require compilation.

If you use, for example, Go, this will not work the same way, since Go programs require compilation, and it is not enough to update source code inside the container. In such case you'll have to build the image again each time you need to make a change.